# Schema must be an instance of GraphQLSchema. Ensure that there are not multiple versions of GraphQL installed in your node_modules directory

Tags: graphql-js

I have an error in graphiql

```
"message": "Schema must be an instance of GraphQLSchema. Also ensure that there are not multiple versions of GraphQL installed in your node_modules directory."
```

I tried  `find node_modules -name graphql`.  But I have only one version of graphql.

schema.js

```
import {
 GraphQLObjectType,
 GraphQLSchema,
 GraphQLInt
 } from 'graphql';

 let count = 0;

  let schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
      count: {
        type: GraphQLInt,
        resolve: function() {
          return count;
        }
      }
    }
  })
});
export default schema;
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "express-graphql": "^0.6.11",
    "graphql": "^0.11.7",
    "mysql": "^2.15.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-relay": "^1.4.1",
    "require-clean": "^0.1.3",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.5"
  }
```

server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import graphQLHTTP from 'express-graphql';
var Schema = require('./data/schema');
const GRAPHQL_PORT = 8080;
let graphQLServer;

 const graphQLApp = express();
  graphQLApp.use('/', graphQLHTTP({
    graphiql: true,
    pretty: true,
    schema: Schema,
  }));
  graphQLServer = graphQLApp.listen(GRAPHQL_PORT, () => {
    console.log(
      GraphQL server is now running.
 );
 });
```

Server works well And I can get GraphQL server is running in console. But graphiql is showing the error.

Any idea what is wrong in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is syntax error in schema.js. `fields` is a function property. This works.

```
let schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: ()=> ({ 
      count: {
        type: GraphQLInt,
        resolve:()=> {
          return count;
        }
      }
    })
  })
});
```

server.js

```
import Schema from './data/schema';
```